# Use string in Highcharts data

Tags: javascript, php, string, symfony, highcharts

I'm working with Symfony2. I pass a string to a view where I display a pie chart and I'm trying to pass this string into the data section.

My string is: `[['EURUSD',7],['GBPUSD',0],['USDEUR',1]]`

I get it from my symfony controller like this:

```
<?php {{liste}}; ?>
```

but when I try to put it in the data like this the chart don't load correctly

```
<script>
...
  series: [{ type: 'pie',name: '',data:  "<?php  {{liste}};?>" 
...
</script>
```

but when I do

```
data: [['EURUSD',7],['GBPUSD',0],['USDEUR',1]]
```

it works!

EDIT:this is the code of my view

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Chart</title>
<!-- Chargement des librairies: Jquery & highcharts -->
<script type='text/javascript' src="{{asset('bundles/user/js/jquery.min.js')}}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{asset('bundles/user/js/highcharts.js')}}" ></script>
</head>

<body>
    <p><div align="center">{{liste}}</div></p>
    <p>
<!-- Chargement des variables, et paramètres de Highcharts -->

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
    var chart;
    $(document).ready(function() {

        Highcharts.getOptions().colors = Highcharts.map(Highcharts.getOptions().colors, function(color) {
            return {
                radialGradient: { cx: 0.5, cy: 0.3, r: 0.7 },
                stops: [
                    [0, color],
                    [1, Highcharts.Color(color).brighten(-0.3).get('rgb')]
                ]
            };
        });

        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                plotBackgroundColor: null,
                plotBorderWidth: null,
                plotShadow: false
            },
            title: {
                text: 'myData'
            },
            tooltip: {
                pointFormat: '<b>{point.percentage}%</b>',
                percentageDecimals: 1
            },
            plotOptions: {
                pie: {
                    allowPointSelect: true,
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        color: '#000000',
                        connectorColor: '#000000',
                        formatter: function() {
                            return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ Highcharts.numberFormat(this.percentage, 1) +' %';
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            series: [{
                type: 'pie',
                name: '',
                data:  "<?php  {{liste}};?>" 

            }]
        });
    });

});</script>
<!-- Affichage du graphique -->
<div id="container" style="width:100%; height:400px;"> 
</div></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which template engine are you using for your project? Twig? Simple PHP?

Comment: i use twig,i already verified the content of my passed string and its identique to what i pass when it works.

Comment: So the @Thomas answer is the good way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your string is already in a JS format, and you are passing it to the template as a string too. Remove the quotes and it should work. Also, you may want to use the `raw` filter so twig wont escape your chars. Example:

```
series: [{
    type: 'pie',
    name: '',
    data: {{ liste|raw }}
}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Since I believe you use twig as template engine, forget about the php including brackets.

```
<script>
...
  series: [{ type: 'pie',name: '',data: "{{liste}}" }]
...
</script>
```

Comment: when i do that the chart doesn't display at all!!

Comment: What does your final HTML look like ?

Comment: if you use twig for template engine you should not use <?php brackets in your template, you use {{ liste }}.

This could help you further: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html

Comment: Yes i know that,i do as you recommanded in my views since i'm using twig.but here even if i do {{MyString}} it doesn't work.as u can see i used it in the body to display my string to be sure it's right!!

Answer (score 1):

Problem is with json interpretation of the value, so use json_encode filter

```
series: [{
    type: 'pie',
    name: '',
    data: {{ liste|json_encode|raw }}
}]
```